# Prove that there are proper classes A, B such that $A \cap B= 0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am studying the book "introduction to set theory", by Donald Monk, and I am having difficulties to solve some exercises about proper classes, could anybody help me?

here they are:

Prove that: 
there are proper classes A, B such that $A \cap B= 0$
there are proper classes A, B such that $A \subset B$ and that $B-A$ is a proper class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question take $A= \{ \mbox{finite sets} \} $ and $B= \{ \mbox{infinite sets} \} $.

For the second question take $A= \{ \mbox{finite sets} \} $ and $B= \{ \mbox{sets} \} $.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Singletons are never pairs.